# CloudFormation Parameter Template Error : Parameter is non alphanumeric

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameters, aws-cloudformation

I am using

```
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://template.json
```

and then getting error:

```
CloudFormation Parameter Template Error : Parameter is non alphanumeric
```

Following code shows my `params.json` and `template.json` files.

**params.json**

```
[
    {
        "ParameterKey": "name_for_abc",
        "ParameterValue": "abc"
    }
]
```

**template.json**

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
    "Description": "some text",
    "Parameters": {
        "name": {
            "Description": "name_of_abc",
            "Type": "String"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "LambdaFunctionAuto": {
            "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
            "Properties": {
                "Environment": {
                    "Variables": {
                        "name_of_abc": {
                            "Ref": "name_of_abc"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider saved parameters using SSM as explained in this post https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/integrating-aws-cloudformation-with-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/

Comment: Avoid to use the _ and - characters in the name of your resources, parameters, etc.

Comment: Duplicate of the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62304986/943773

Answer (score 35):

To fix the problem, rename the parameter `name_of_abc` to `nameofabc` in the `params.json` file and the `Parameters` section of the CloudFormation template.

From the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#parameters-section-structure-requirements):

> Each parameter must be given a logical name (also called logical ID), which must be alphanumeric and unique among all logical names within the template.