# How to supply non-alphanumeric parameter type to AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Hi I'm creating a CloudFormation stack from CLI and trying to supply a url parameter. I have given the type as `String` as I couldn't find anything specific for URL's [HERE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types)

The problem is, when I give it as `Type: String`, I get this error:

`An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template format error: Parameter name TELEPHONY_URL is non alphanumeric.`

This is my parameter json:

`{
    "ParameterKey": "TELEPHONY_URL",
    "ParameterValue": "https://telephony.crm4b2c.com/1/api/Telephony/LogCallComplete/"
 }`

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the parameter name `TELEPHONY_URL` must be alphanumeric, no special characters.

So try updating it for example `TELEPHONYURL` or `TelephonyURL`

Comment: No problem, glad I could help resolve your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than running into these errors one-by-one at deployment time, the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) and the [CloudFormation Linter Visual Studio Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kddejong.vscode-cfn-lint) can show these errors inline while working on CloudFormation templates:

```sh
E2003 Parameter TELEPHONY_URL has invalid name.  Name has to be alphanumeric.
```

[image: CloudFormation Linter Visual Studio Code extension screenshot]

Comment: Looks interesting. Will check it out for sure. Thanks